# Message Box Sharepoint Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, messagebox

hi i'm having a problem with sharepoint web part
so i want to  call message box everytime user input is wrong
so for example if user input password more than 15 than there will be message box that says"Password lenght max 15"
when i wrote
Messagebox.show("Password lenght max 15") it works fine,but if i try to fill password more than 15 than it return error that says sharepoint cannot support message box
so i'm wondering if there's a way to use message box in sharepoint
any help will be appreciated 
FYI i put the Messagebox.show in my save button click
thank you
sorry if my english are bad

Comment: Messagebox = Forms (e.g. desktop application), something totally different. This is not really SharePoint related. To show an alert, you need javascript, e.g. alert('Test').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message box is not supported in ASP.NET Application so similar in Sharepoint.

SharePoint Support MessageDialog.

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options)
```

If you want to open through server side, then you need to create JS function and call it through C# or as below

```
hyperLink.NavigateUrl = "javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog('" + url + "')";
```

You can send proper string as well using options.

Answer (score 1):

This may be old post, but accepted answer does not work too good in Sharepoint 2013, at least for me. Instead, I have to use this script:

```
<script ID="callMyFunction">
    function myFunction() {
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerHTML = 'Hello World, I am the dialog content';
        var options = {}
        options.title = "Name of dialog";
        options.width = 400;
        options.height = 300;
        options.html = element;//MSDN states it should be string, which is wrong. This is supposed to be DOM element

        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);//This starts function "showModalDialog" after loading "sp.ui.dialog.js", if it was not loaded yet.
    }
</script>
```

and call it from my WebPart like this:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "callMyFunction", "myFunction()", true);
```

If you want to use Ali Murtaza answer, remember to load script below, as it seems to be not loaded by default:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```